# How to sync mail accounts between iMac and iPad2 properly?

Tags: mail.app, imac, ipad

I'm trying to sync my email accounts between my new iMac and an iPad 2.
The problem is that if I read or delete a message on the iMac, the same email appears on iPad as not deleted and not read.

Any help?
Cheers

Comment: Use IMAP for email. It's designed to solve exactly this issue.

Comment: What account are you using? we can then tell you if you can enable IMAP.

Comment: Will change to imap. Now and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the account type might be POP instead of IMAP. POP stores messages and all message attributes on each client (iMac, iPad, etc). IMAP stores messages and attributes on the server, so every client has the same view of the messages (including unread/read state). So, the solution for you is to use IMAP if the account supports it.